# Allocating memory in a php extension

Tags: php, c, pointers, php-extension

I'm not good with pointers in C)

Having trouble with memory allocation in my PHP extension.  I'm trying to call a function that returns an array of floats.

I wrote a small test script in C, and it works.

Basically it's,

```
float *fld;
...
ier = c_fstluk(fld, key, &ni, &nj, &nk);
...
// Read the array as a 2d field
for (i=0; i<ni; i++) {
   for (j=0; j<nj; j++) {
      // Values come transposed..
      printf("%15.6E", *(fld+(ni*j)+i));
      if (j<nj-1) printf(", ");
   }
   printf("\n");
 }
```

([full code](https://github.com/kheaactua/php_fstd/blob/master/ext/fstd/testFstd.c))

Here I don't have to `malloc` or `free` anything.  (at least I don't think so.  In the fortran version of this code and function, I need to `allocate()` fld first.)

In my PHP extension however, the same code returns a seg fault.

When I `emalloc` and `efree` (or just `malloc` and `free`) fld before calling `c_fstluk`, it works, but I get tonnes of memory errors.

```
[Wed Jan  9 15:34:33 2013]  Script:  '/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php'
/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/Zend/zend_API.c(1295) :  Freeing 0x10D953060 (72 bytes), script=/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php
/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/Zend/zend_hash.c(412) : Actual location (location was relayed)
Last leak repeated 779 times
[Wed Jan  9 15:34:33 2013]  Script:  '/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php'
/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/Zend/zend_API.c(1292) :  Freeing 0x10D9531A0 (32 bytes), script=/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php
Last leak repeated 779 times
[Wed Jan  9 15:34:33 2013]  Script:  '/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php'
ext/fstd/fstd.c(414) :  Freeing 0x10D9538D0 (72 bytes), script=/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php
/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/Zend/zend_API.c(982) : Actual location (location was relayed)
Last leak repeated 29 times
[Wed Jan  9 15:34:33 2013]  Script:  '/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php'
/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/Zend/zend_hash.c(450) :  Freeing 0x10D954C08 (256 bytes), script=/Users/matt/aurams/trunk/web/php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php
Last leak repeated 29 times
=== Total 1620 memory leaks detected ===
```

([Full code with `emalloc` commented out](https://github.com/kheaactua/php_fstd/blob/master/ext/fstd/fstd.c), line ~398)

I bet I'm missing something simple here..

So to summarize, in stand alone C program, stuff works without any allocation.  In PHP extension, it works when I allocate space, but throws memory errors, when I don't allocate space, it seg faults.

Help?  Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.management.php

Comment: @MarcB - I read that before writing this (that's where I found out about `emalloc`), but I still don't know how to proceed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [document](http://people.sca.uqam.ca/~caron/divers/RPN_Standard_Files.pdf), `c_fstluk(buffer, key, &ni, &nj, &nk)` reads data into *buffer*, therefore the buffer (*fld*) has to be allocated.

In the C version, if should normally not work having *fld* unallocated. But depending on your system etc... or some luck, the `fld *` pointer may point to a random space that is not written-protected (works but, of course, this is extremely dangerous).

Therefore the extension has also to allocate the memory (either permanent or PHP request-life only depending on your ext) and then release it - in your case it is a temporary allocation, and has to be released before leaving the *php_function*.

What I can see in the code you provided, while commented out

- the `emalloc` does the allocation
- then you force the module to return `0` since you want to test this part (and not the PHP vars creation etc...)
- *then* you `efree` *fld*
- thus *fld* is not released and creates memory leaks

So it is probably a simple mistake, the `efree` should be moved just before the return of the function.

```
fld = emalloc(ni*nj*sizeof(float*)); /* sizeof(float)  INSTEAD? */

// Read the field pointed by the given key
ier = c_fstluk(fld, key, &ni, &nj, &nk);

/* ... */

php_printf("\nDone.\n");

efree(fld);

RETURN_LONG(0);
```

**edit based on comments**

- `(float *)` allocation changed to `(float)`
- `ALLOC_INIT_ZVAL(arow)` to be done for all iterations (source bottom)

Comment: I'm really impressed you looked up (and found) documentation for the RPN standard library.  Most of that stuff is non-public.

I took your advice, but I still have the memory errors.  The `RETURN_LONG(0)` was only there for testing, really I want the function to return `return_val` (a zval array).  I [recommited](https://github.com/kheaactua/php_fstd/blob/master/ext/fstd/fstd.c) the code as you suggest, re-built PHP, but am getting the memory leak errors still.  (though, it does work.. I can read the values no problem.)

Maybe I need to free `arow` and `afld`?

Comment: I changed the allocation size from float* to float, but I got the same result. :(  About being double/float, I'm pretty sure it's a float, the reasons I think this are because: 1) In fortran it'd be a `real`, and typically `real`'s are `float`s as far as I understand, and the code defines it as a `WORD` (a macro it defines), 2) if I followed it's definition right, it's a `float`.  3) Also, the values I get are right.  If I were declaring it as the wrong size, I'd expect them to be wrong.  (I compare them against my fortran programs that output the same field.)

Comment: Your *ALLOC_INIT_ZVAL* created variables should be automatically released when the request ends. And I don't think the problem is in the `c_` functions (that we don't see) since PHP could not see the leaks of mem allocated via `malloc`. Any other `emalloc` somewhere not freed? Try to make arguments and constants (in C and PHP) vary to see if the number and size of leaks change. Thus you can identify where the leaks are created.

Comment: I've never debugged like that.  So, pretty much, declare arbitrary constants in the C and PHP program, and see if the memory addresses or sizes in the report change?  How would I use that to identify where the leak is created?  (I'm really inexperienced finding memory leaks :(  sorry for all the questions.)    One thing I noticed that really creates more memory erros is putting a `ALLOC_INIT_ZVAL(return_value);` before `array_init(return_value)`

Comment: I think the `ALLOC_INIT_ZVAL(arow);` should be moved just after the `for`, ie line 417, just before `array_init(arow);`. It is my understanding that currently `arow` is copied into `afld` and then is re-created as an array and thus could generate the leak. The new init should release the var first. Please try, if it doesn't work (I think it will) we'd have to delete `arow` at the end of the `for`.

Comment: That did it!  Awesome!  Thanks!

When I wrote that code, I was wondering if that would be an issue, I figured re-initializing it would mean I would be writing to the beginning of it (which worked), but I didn't realize that it should be de-allocated and re-allocated each time.  Why is that by the way?  If this were Fortran, I'd have `allocate`d() the size I need, and just recycle that, only deallocating it at the end.

Comment: If init is not done for each iteration, the part that checks the object *reference count* and release its memory before it is re-assigned (initially to *null* then to an array) is missing. Why is it that way? The *zval* functions in C do actually work with complex objects that represent a PHP *$variable*. Your algorithm fits what would do some PHP code. The idea in an ext is *Stick to C data as much as possible, then finally deal with PHP objects* that are the interface with the PHP script. Maybe the algo could be optimized to work C float arrays to avoid the many current allocs / deallocs?